# How to call method from inside a method?

Tags: python

```
class A:
  def a(self):
    print 'a'
  def b(self):
    print 'b'
    a()
```

Comment: Please read an introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class methods need their first argument to be `self`. You can then call the `a` method with `self.a()`:

```
class A:
  def a(self):
    print 'a'
  def b(self):
    print 'b'
    self.a()
```

Comment: Unlike `self` in Ruby or `this` in Java, there isn't anything special about `self` in Python -- it's just the name (by convention) given to the first parameter of a method -- however, *I would by most irritated to run into code that didn't follow that convention in Python*.